# pythonically editing a list of tupples of strings

Tags: python, list

mysql has output a list of tuples of the form

```
a=[("1","2","3"),("4","5","6"),("7","8","9")]
```

I want a list of tuples of the form

```
c=[("2","3"),("5","6"),("8","9")]
```

i.e. the last two elements of each tuple, so i can put that into a my sql executemany command and get the next piece of data.

my intuition was that i could get the desired matrix with the command

```
c=[for b in a: b[1:]]
```

but python, doesn't like that. Why doesn't that work, and what's the most pythonic way of getting the desired list of tuples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since, you want the last two elements of each tuple, using the slice `[1:]` *(like in the other answers)* won't work when the number of elements in each tuple is not 3.

Instead, use a list comprehension with the negative slice of `[:-2]`:

```
a = [("1","2","3"),("4","5","6"),("7","8","9")]
a = [t[-2:] for t in a]
print(a)
```

Output:

```
[('2', '3'), ('5', '6'), ('8', '9')]
```

Answer (score 5):

You have your syntax slightly wrong, but have taken the right approach.

```py
c = [b[1:] for b in a]
```

Answer (score 4):

You'll want to slice each `i`tem in `a`:

```
>>> a = [("1","2","3"),("4","5","6"),("7","8","9")]
>>> [i[1:] for i in a]
[('2', '3'), ('5', '6'), ('8', '9')]
```

Answer (score 4):

You can go through like this, here for loops will go at end:

```
a=[(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9)]
c=[b[1:] for b in a]
print(c)
```